llamaindex not taking entire document as context
I am building a small RAG that takes in json as context and provides response based on json data (array of objects). The flow itself is simple.

Use llamaindex
Load json as document
Embed the document
Use query engine to query the document

However, when I prompt to respond with all the provided context, the response comes back with just couple of items from the array. When I reduce the number of fields in each item (just for testing purposes) the response contains all the items. So I am sure it is to do with the size of the document (although the json itself is just 10kb).
I did try chunking the document per item in the json and it makes the response worse. I have run out of ideas as I am relative new to this.
Below is the snippet of the code. I am using OpenAI with
Settings.llm = new OpenAI({ apiKey: openAIKeys.open_ai_api_key });
Settings.embedModel = new OpenAIEmbedding({ model: "text-embedding-ada-002" });
const essay = await fs.readFile('./report.json', 'utf-8');
    const documents = [new Document({
      text: essay,
      id_: `essay_`
    })];
    if (!this.#cachedVectorIndex) {
      this.#cachedVectorIndex = await VectorStoreIndex.fromDocuments(documents);
    }

    const queryEngine = this.#cachedVectorIndex.asQueryEngine();
const prompt = `Return all the context that has been provided in the report.`;
    const results = await queryEngine.query({
      query: prompt,
    });
    

Any ideas would be appreciated.
